# style="display:none;" breaking onclick

Tags: javascript

```
<div id="bottom_right" style="display:none;">
    <input type="text" name="mytext" id="mytext" onclick="myFn('mytext')">
</div>

function myFn(id){
    document.getElementById(id).value = 'hello';
}

function showForm() {
    document.getElementById("bottom_right").style.display = 'block';
}

function showRoom() {
    clearRoommates();
    var root = document.getElementById("bottom_left");
    root.innerHTML="";
var inputRadio = "<h3>Select a room from below</h3><br/>";
    inputRadio += "<div id = 'left'><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>510</label><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>520</label>";
    inputRadio += "<label><input name='rad' type='radio'>530</label><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>540</label></div>";
    inputRadio += "<div id = 'right'><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>550</label><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>560</label>";
    inputRadio += "<label><input name='rad' type='radio'>570</label><label><input name='rad' type='radio'>580</label></div>";
    root.innerHTML=inputRadio;
    var element = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    for (var i=element.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
        element[i].setAttribute('onclick',"showForm()");
    }
}
```

There is additional code elsewhere that changes the display style from 'none' to 'block'. When a user clicks the input box it should automatically display the text 'hello'. This works fine if I remove the style from the div or set it to 'block' initially.

Why doesn't this work when the display style is initially 'none'?

*edited to include display change function*

Comment: How would you click that input if it isnt visible?

Comment: There's a button that changes the style from 'none' to 'block'.

Comment: Post that code as well

Comment: checked it works fine if you click the button to show the div.

Comment: Are you receiving any errors? Anything in [the console](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/console)? What you've posted seems to work as expected: http://jsfiddle.net/uhhK5/.

Comment: `element[i].setAttribute('onclick', 'showForm()');` shouldn't it be `element[i].addEventListener('click', showForm);`?

Comment: I've added some more code to the original question. The button to display the hidden block is created via javascript. When I add a button directly to the html it works fine.

Comment: Thanks! Using addEventListener worked.

Answer (score 0):

"Please note that a display of 'none' does not create an invisible box; it creates **no box at all**."

http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html

This is the reason you cannot click on the div or it's children (input).

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that the `onclick="myFn('mytext')` in the markup is being replaced during this loop:

```
var element = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
for (var i=element.length-1; i>=0; i--) {
    element[i].setAttribute('onclick',"showForm()");
}
```

So, when you click the `<input>`, it just calls `showForm()` again rather than `myFn('mytext')`.

You can exclude that `<input>` from the collection by using `getElementsByTagName()` on `root` rather than `document`:

```
var element = root.getElementsByTagName("input");
```

Then, the loop will only affect `root`'s descendants rather than all `<input>`s throughout the `document`.